# Recursion with pointers sum of digits

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, digits, function-definition

I tried to build a recursion function using pointers that puts the digits with an even index in one pointer and the digits with the odd index to a different one.

For example:

The input `123`: `3` has the `index of 0` so it will go to `*even`.

`2` has the `index of 1` so it will go to `*odd`.

`1` has the `index of 2` so it will go to `*even`.

and in the end `*even` will have the value of `1+3 = 4` and `*odd` will have the value of `2`.

But I had problems with this function so I tried to do a simplified version of it and It didn't work.
So the simplified version puts the sum of all the digits in `*sum`:

```
void main()
{
    int num = 25; 
    int x = 0; 
    sumDigits(num, &x);
    printf("%d", x);
}

void sumDigits(int num, int* sum)
{
    if (num >= 0 && num <= 9)
    {
        *sum = num;
    }
    else
    {
        *sum = *sum + num % 10;
        sumDigits(num/10, sum);
    }
}
```

But it still won't work properly.
If someone could tell me what's wrong with this function then I could understand how to it and the original one as well.

Comment: Change `int *x = 0;` to be `int x = 0;` If you compile with warnings turned up your compiler should tell you that `&x` is not a compatible type for the required `int *` as it is `int **`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the clarification. I changed to what you said but the function still won't work.

Comment: `sumDigits(num/10, &sum);` -> `sumDigits(num/10, sum);`. Turn on/up compiler warnings.

Comment: Again, changed it as you said, no compiler warnings now but the function still won't work.. :)

Comment: Are you sure there are no more warnings? Is that your complete code? Where are the header includes and forward declaration for `sumDigits`? Do you have those in your real code or is that the actual complete code?

Comment: Yes this is the complete code, after the changes you suggested I have no warnings as you can see, but when I print x the output is 2 instead of 7 https://gyazo.com/6689e5c463ea77721709cdb2d1bf888b

Comment: `*sum = num;` -> `*sum += num;` Suggest you learn to debug effectively to be able to find these logic problems yourself. Run your program in a debugger and step thru it line by line.

Comment: Please elaborate "won't work properly". At least for the current state of your code. Describe the misbehaviour, report your observations.

Comment: You are asking about odd/even splilt sums, but then show a simplified code for one sum, which does not work. Can you focus your question on either how to fix the simple one or provide working simple code and ask about doing the odd/even split?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to handle both an even and an odd digit in each function call.

Like:

```
void sumDigits(unsigned int num, unsigned int* even, unsigned int* odd)
{
  // Handle even digit
  *even += num % 10;
  num /= 10;

  // Handle odd digit
  *odd += num % 10;
  num /= 10;

  // If there are still digits to be handled
  if (num)
  {
    // Do the recursive call
    sumDigits(num, even, odd);
  }
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int num = 123;
    unsigned int even = 0, odd = 0;
    sumDigits(num, &even, &odd);
    printf("even=%d odd=%d", even, odd);
}
```

That said... this problem is **not** suitable for recursion a simple loop will be much more efficient.

```
void sumDigits(unsigned int num, unsigned int* even, unsigned int* odd)
{
  while (num)
  {
    *even += num % 10;
    num /= 10;

    *odd += num % 10;
    num /= 10;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I know that a recursion is not the suitable solution but It was an exercise and I was asked to use a recursion with pointers. BTW why did you use unsigned ints as opposed to normal ones.

Comment: @Saldeat I used unsigned because I thought you only wanted non-negative numbers (don't know where I got that from...). Anyway, using `int` and negative numbers should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function `sumDigits` must be declared before main and according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

That is you need to write

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sumDigits(int num, int* sum);

int main( void )
{
    //...
}
```

There is neither sense to declare the first parameter of the function as having the signed integer type `int` because it seems the function does not deal with negative numbers.

The first parameter should have the type `unsigned long long`. In this case you can call the function for an object of any fundamental unsigned integer type.

The function has a logical error. Its last recursive call overwrites the value stored in sum that was calculated in preceding recursive calls of the function due to this if statement

```
if (num >= 0 && num <= 9)
{
    *sum = num;
}
```

Also pay attention to that the user can pass by reference the second argument that was not initialized. In this case the function will have undefined behavior.

As for your mentioned function that should calculate suns of digits in even and odd positions then it can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void digits_sums( unsigned long long int x, unsigned int *even, unsigned int *odd )
{
    const unsigned long long int Base = 10;
    
    x == 0 
    ? ( *even = x, *odd = x ) 
    : ( digits_sums( x / Base / Base, even, odd ), *even += x % Base, *odd += x / Base %Base );   
}

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned int x = 123456789;
    unsigned int even;
    unsigned int odd;
    
    digits_sums( x, &even, &odd );
    
    printf( "The sum of digits in even positions is %u\n"
            "The sum of digits in odd positions  is %u\n",
            even, odd );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The sum of digits in even positions is 25
The sum of digits in odd positions  is 20
```